# Azure WORM/ immutable retention lock on containers for legacy java SDK

Tags: azure, sdk

I wan to set up a [immutable policy for blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutability-policies-manage?tabs=azure-powershell) using the Java "Legacy" SDK (version 8.3), but I can't seem to find any documentation showing how to do this, or if it's even possible from the legacy version. The website shows how to do this from the portal, CLI and PowerShell, but I've yet to find any reference to the Java SDK. Am I missing some documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest thing to docs you'd be able to find on this would be the SDK documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.fluent.models.immutabilitypolicyinner?view=azure-java-stable and here for legal holds: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.fluent.models.legalholdinner?view=azure-java-stable.

It doesn't seem like there is a lot of great documentation on how to use them, but at least these give you the class and method names.